# Entity Framework, how do I force a default value in sub-class?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, frameworks, entity, default

I'm using VS2010 model designer and trying to figure out how to force a default value in a sub-class for a field that is inherited in the parent class. For example, when a Products_Hardware object is created, I want product_Typeid to be forced to a certain value.

### Table structure:

**Parent Class:**

Table Products:
product_Typeid,
idnumber,
cost,
supplyAmount

**Associate table with Products-**

Table productType:
product_Typeid,
product_Typeshort,
product_Description

**Sub-classes of Products:**

Table Products_Hardware:
weight,
manufacturer,
warrantytime

Table Products_Software:
developername,
version number,
release date,
platforms,
mediatype

Comment: Intialise the value in the constructor of Products_Hardware?

Comment: Are you able to provide more details about the model - what code generation strategy / version of EF?

Comment: How do you implement inheritance? TPT, TPC, TPH?